# Pass data from all pages to json react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, forms, routes

I have couple of pages with forms in them, when I go to other page via link, using Routing, last page information is lost. I need to keep all information to submit from the last page.

I tried passing data with **:** `history.push("./Skills", { fname:{fname}, lname:{lname} });`

but it didn't work. How can I stop pages from refreshing to keep data ?

Comment: Please use localstroge for save data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a global store.

You can use Redux for this.

It's a little bit complicated to understand it when you never used it.

But it make the job.

Redux website: https://redux.js.org/

Dev Ed Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVpUuw9XSjY

Comment: You can also use the localstorage but it's not very clean